# How does Elasticsearch manage its shards?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have three nodes working together. On those nodes I have five indexes, each having 5 primary shards and each primary shard has 2 replicas. It looks like this (i cut to see only two indices out of 5 ):
![IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/2ez1wjt.png

As you can see on the picture:
- the node 1 has primary shards 0 and 3 (and replicas 1,2 and 4)
- the node 2 has primary shards 2 (and replicas 0, 1, 3 and 4)
- the node 3 has primary shards 1 and 4 (and replicas 0 ,2 and 3)
and this is the case **for each index** (the 5 of them).

I understand that if I restart my nodes this "organisation" will change but still the "look" of index will be the same as index2, 3, 4, 5. For example, after restarting, I would have:
- the node 1 has primary shards 1 and 2 (and replicas 0, 3 and 4)
- the node 2 has primary shards 3 (and replicas 0, 1, 2 and 4)
- the node 3 has primary shards 0 and 4 (and replicas 1 ,2 and 3)
and this would be the case **for each index** (the 5 of them).

Is there a reason why I find always the same pattern for each of my index?

Thanks

Comment: And why do you think the shards should be spread differently after restart?

Comment: @Andrei Stefan The fact is that after restart my shards are spread differently as they were before restart. What I wonder is why every index has the same pattern.